# System command hanging when launched from within Java app but not from command line

Tags: java

I have a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) system command (an executable JAR file) that runs successfully if launched manually from the command line but hangs indefinitely when launched from within a Java application (v1.8.0_191).

I didn't write the executable JAR (it's called Tabula, an open-source PDF parser, but I don't think what the system command does is actually relevant to my problem). The executable JAR file takes the path to a PDF file as one of it's arguments, and it outputs JSON data to standard out. The average completion time of the command is usually just a few seconds.

For the majority of the PDF files that I process, there are no problems, but for a small bunch of PDFs the application that I've written hangs. I've discovered that the problem is the executable JAR command is not returning, so my application is waiting indefinitely. If I run `ps -elf | grep java` I can see the command is still running. Occasionally, the process will consume a very small amount of memory and CPU, but I have no idea what it's doing.

However, if I run that exact same executable JAR command myself on the command line, then it completes and returns the expected output in a few seconds. On the face it you would think that because the issue is not random and is confined to specific PDF input files, then it must be the files that the executable JAR does not like. If that was true, then why does the command *always* complete successfully if I run it manually from the command line.

I've extracted the relevant code into something smaller and more testable:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 1) {
        throw new Exception("Expected: folio ID as argument");
    }
    String folioID = args[0];

    String[] command = new String[] {
            "java", "-jar", Config.tabulaJARFile,
            "--stream",
            "--format", "JSON",
            "--pages", "all",
            String.format("%s/%s.pdf", Config.TABULA_INPUT_DIR, folioID)
    };

    System.out.println("Executing ==> " + String.join(" ", command));
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    System.out.println("Waiting...");
    int exitCode = process.waitFor();

    if (exitCode != 0) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid exit code ["+exitCode+"]");
    }
    System.out.println("Retrieving input stream...");
    InputStream output = process.getInputStream();

    String jsonData = IOUtils.toString(output, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(jsonData);

}
```

Example output of a run would be:

```
Executing ==> java -jar /home/ubuntu/tabula/tabula-1.0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar --stream --format JSON --pages all /home/ubuntu/tabula/input/CK12345.pdf
Waiting...
```

...and that will hang indefinitely, but if I run that exact same command myself on the command line it will complete in a few seconds. I've also tried creating the command with a `ProcessBuilder` but the result is the same. Why might this be happening?

---

It seems that if I redirect the output of the process using a `ProcessBuilder` e.g. `processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)` then the command completes successfully, but it prints the output to the console instead of letting me capture it in the application. I've managed a workaround by redirecting the output of the command to a file instead, then reading the contents of the file.

Comment: Looks like the product has a Debug class you could invoke instead to see what's happening : "run java -cp ./target/tabula-1.0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar technology.tabula.debug.Debug -h for the available options.". Moreover it has a whole Java API which you could use rather than spawn the command-line tool. If none of this works out for you you could pick thread-dumps of the spawned JVM to try and debug it or to open an issue on github

Comment: @Aaron I came across that Debug option too, but it doesn't actually provide anything useful about the applications progress. I did notice an API was mentioned in a few places before I started working on my application, but I couldn't find any relevant docs (still can't), and I the executable JAR was fine for my needs. But... is this not a Java problem? If I can run it on the command line fine, then surely it must be Java launching and managing the command that's the issue?

Comment: Could be an environment thing too, e.g. encoding, terminal vs non-interactive stdin/out, aliases with additional options, etc. that would in combination with specific PDF content trigger a bug in tabula. Taking thread-dumps would let you know what the JVM is waiting for or busy doing

Comment: BTW is there anything in common in the names of the PDFs that fail?

Comment: The names of the PDFs don't have anything in common. I've just discovered with one of the PDFs that I'm testing if I tell the parser app to process a range of pages that doesn't include the last page, then it completes successfully. If I tell it process only the last page, then it completes successfully too... maybe this problem is specific to Tabula, possibly a bug. I should look into that further I think. I'll try a thread dump too if I need to.

Comment: Use ProcessBuilder, and remember to call its [inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29) method before starting the process.  Processes can hang if their stdout and/or stderr have no destination.

Comment: @VGR yes! that works when I call the inheritIO() method before kicking off the command, and it terminates successfully after a few seconds, but it's printing the output to the console now, which means the getInputStream() of the process returns nothing. Setting `redirectOutput(Redirect.PIPE)` on the process builder just causes the command to hang again

Comment: Call `inheritIO()`, then call `redirectOutput(Redirect.PIPE)`.

Comment: @VGR doesn't work, it hangs again.